# MVC4 sql server 2008 r2 call stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, stored-procedures

i am using `mdf` for sql server 2008 r2 into my mvc4 project.

i can see in my `entities` the stored procedure because i add them when i connected my visual studion project to the mdf.

i want to use a stored procedure.

#### what i have tried

```
MyProjectEntities db = new MyProjectEntities();
int ID;
db.tenantLogin(userName, password, ID);
```

the `tenantLogin` is a stored procedure that uses two input parameters and return the third own as an integer value.

but visual studtion refuses that function.

so please who to call that stored procedrure ? thank you

Comment: Did you map it in the designer?

Comment: @MikeCheel yes into the visual studio that ask me if i want to select the table and the stored proecdure and i said yes and now i can see all the stored procedures as functions in my projectEntities

Comment: So it is working now?

Comment: @MikeCheel no not yet

Comment: It sounds like you did what you were supposed to. Have you validated that you aren't getting an exception taht causes your call to fail?